# Why suddenly do I need to use ob_end_clean() to pass my JSON data?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, post

Suddenly the JSON response encoded by my PHP code is not accepted anymore by my ajax request. It requires using `ob_start();` and `ob_end_clean();` at the beginning and the ending of my PHP code to make it work.
Without this 'fix', the JSON response has a small red dot as first char in the chrome dev console.

I use the last version of xampp for windows as local server and everything worked fine for months until today. It's not clear to me what I have done to trigger this.

That's how I encode and pass data after a select query:

```php
   $data = [];
   while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ) {
    array_push( $data, $row );
   }
   echo json_encode( $data );
   exit();
```

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "/test.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        hello: "hi"
    },
    success: function(response) {
        //i do something with response[0][name]
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
    });
```

The error in the chrome dev console is:

```
    "parsererror" SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ in JSON at position 1
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2
    at l (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
```

I checked the php.ini and commented out the output-buffer option, but it didn't help. Reinstalling xampp didn't help too.
How can I restore the "previous mode": clean JSON without ob commands?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not find out what the small red dot represents (save/hexedit) and where it originates from?

Comment: Probably a Byte Order Mark.

Comment: It's a non-printable hidden Unicode character. Hexedit (thanks for the tip) shows `"ï»¿`. It seems related to the UTF-8 encoded Byte Order Mark.
I just re-saved the files that I was including in every PHP code and the dot disappeared (I commented out portions of my code until it vanished). Now it works, but I didn't touch those `include('somefile.php');` for months. Would be nice to find why this happened. Could it be related to the "Discovery" future of Dreamweaver (ver.19 11193 build)? 
Thanks for the help